# Using Pattern.web to search all Wikipedia is raising "'NoneType' object is not iterable" error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to use `Pattern.web` to search all of Wikipedia for words and phrases that include an apostrophe. This is my latest attempt:

```
from pattern.web import Wikipedia, plaintext

from pattern.web import SEARCH

engine = Wikipedia(language="en")

q = "\"cat's\""

for i in range(1, 2):
    for result in engine.search(q, start=i, count=10, type=SEARCH, cached=True):
        print plaintext(result.text)
        print result.url
        print result.date
        print
```

But I get this error message:

```
for result in engine.search(q, start=i, count=10, type=SEARCH, cached=True):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Question:

- Is it even possible to do what I'm trying to do?
- If it is, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to the [Wikipedia `SearchEngine` documentation](http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-web#wikipedia), you'll notice that your attempt to iterate is misguided and your query may be erroneous as well:

> `Wikipedia.search()` returns a single `WikipediaArticle` for the given (case-sensitive) query, which is the title of an article.

(Note that this means that `start` and `count` can only be 1.)

I would venture to guess, without downloading the `pattern` library and trying this myself, that since [there is no Wikipedia article entitled "cat's"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat%27s), so you get `None` back.

So, is it possible to do what you are trying to do? Yes. Refer again to the documentation:

> `Wikipedia.index()` returns an iterator over all article titles on Wikipedia.

You might do something like this:

```
for title in engine.index():
    article = engine.search(title)
    # do your string pattern searching here
```

I answered this to the best of my ability without downloading `pattern` and trying it myself, so YMMV.